# "The declared package '' does not match the expected package "AssignmentOne.java"" -Java -VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio, path, vscode-debugger

Why am I getting this error in VS Code?

Things I've tried:

I am attempting to only run the file, `ScannerInputDemo.java`, but VSCode is also attempting to run the other `.java` files in my `/Intro To Java` folder.

I've tried modifying my `launch.json` file to remove the configuration for the `AssignmentOne.java` file hoping that it wouldn't attempt to read that file

**Specs**: I'm using a Mac Book Pro 13", mid 2009.

My **version check** is:

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)
```

**VSCode Version:**

```
Version: 1.45.1
Commit: 5763d909d5f12fe19f215cbfdd29a91c0fa9208a
Date: 2020-05-14T08:33:47.663Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 7.2.4
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 15.6.0
```

Below is a screenshot of my VS Code window showing the file hierarchy and debug results.

[image]

Comment: can you please share how are you trying to run your java program?

Comment: I am running the debugger for Java extension in for VS Code. I can separately compile the files and run them in my terminal, but I would like to get more familiar with how VSCode works and how to debug Java files.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.

Issue was in `.classpath` file, present in the project directory.

It contained

```
classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src"
```

I updated it to

```
classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"
```

and it worked.